# NetSuite Script to Make Department (Lines) Mandatory if a certain GL Account is selected

Tags: netsuite

How to code or make user even script making lines department mandatory if Expense GL codes is selected in the transaction?

Answer (score 3):

You will most likely want a Client Script for this that uses the `validateLine` event handler.

This will allow you to prevent the addition of the line at all if it doesn't meet your acceptance criteria. You cannot specifically modify the column to make it "mandatory" in the UI (i.e. add an asterisk to it), but the script can enforce the logic so that the line does not get added and alerts the user appropriately.

The `validateLine` event handler function you choose just needs to check whatever conditions you have and return `false` if the line should not be added or `true` if it should be added.

The only way to do this in a User Event script is to throw an Error, which is intrusive and usually means the user will lose all the data they just entered, returning them to a blank form.